# How to make a POPAnimation loop

Tags: ios, facebook-pop

How can I have a loop animation with Facebook POP framework.

I tried to set `NO` for a property named `removedOnCompletion` in the `POPBasicAnimation` class but It doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create an endless animation with pop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954443/create-an-endless-animation-with-pop)

Comment: Doesn't have a easy way?

Answer (score 9):

[Version 1.0.7 of Facebook-POP](https://github.com/facebook/pop/releases/tag/1.0.7) has been released and now includes repeat functionality and autoreverse.

To create a endlessly repeating animation set

`animation.repeatForever = YES;`.

There are also properties `repeatCount` and `autoreverses`.